# R: Saving Output as xlsx in for loop

Tags: r

*Using (openxlsx) package to write xlsx files.*
I have a variable that is a vector of numbers

```
x <- 1:8
```

I then paste ".xlsx" to the end of each element of x to later create an xlsx file

```
new_x <- paste(x,".xlsx", sep = "")
```

I then write.xlsx using the ("openxlsx") package in a forloop to create new xlsx files

```
for (i in x) {
for (j in new_x) {
write.xlsx(i,j)
}}
```

When I open ("1.xlsx" - "8.xlsx"), all the files only have the number "8" on them. What I don't understand is why it doesn't have the number 1 for 1.xlsx - 7 for 7.xlsx, why does the 8th one overwrite everything else.

I even tried creating a new output for the dataframes as most others suggested

```
for (i in x) {
for (j in new_x) {
output[[i]] <- i    

write.xlsx(output[[i]],j)
}}
```

And it still comes up with the same problem. I don't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Add `print(i)` and `print(j)` to your loop and see what'll happen when `i = 8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating each Excel file multiple times because you have nested loops.  Try just using a single loop, and referring to an element of new_x.

```
x <- 1:8
new_x <- paste(x,".xlsx", sep = "")
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    write.xlsx(i,new_x[i])
}
```

if you want to read a number of .csv files and save them as xlsx files it is a similar approach, you still want to only have a single for loop such as:

```
# Define directory of where to look for csv files and where to save Excel files
csvDirectory <- "C:/Foo/Bar/"
ExcelDirectory <- paste0(Sys.getenv(c("USERPROFILE")),"\\Desktop")

# Find all the csv files of interest
csvFiles <- list.files(csvDirectory,"*.csv")

# Go through the list of files and for each one read it into R, and then save it as Excel
for (i in seq_along(csvFiles)) {
  csvFile <- read.csv(paste0(csvDirectory,"/",csvFiles[i]))
  write.xlsx(csvFile, paste0(ExcelDirectory,"/",gsub("\\.csv$","\\.xlsx",csvFiles[i])))
}
```

Comment: What if instead of 1:8 there was a vector of txt files and I had to read.csv each one? if I use read.csv(i) is there a variable I should turn it to (i again?) within the forloop?

Comment: I also believe that the problem was only temporarily fixed with seq_along function. Is there a way to do this without the seq_along

Comment: You can use `seq` or `seq_len` to generate a sequence.

Comment: Kerry, is there possibly a solution to writing .xlsx files [in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78143875/16762740) as well?