# write xlsx files from a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list, function, xlsx

Suppose we have a list of data frames called `list_data`.

Our goal is to write a separate `.xlsx` file maybe using `openxlsx::write.xlsx()` for each `District` where each file has two subsheets (aka tabs) named after the data.frames in `list_data` (in this case, these names are `one` and `two`).

Because some `District`s are only included in `one` OR `two`, for such `District`s one of the subsheets will be empty which is OK.

File names can be the names of the `District`s.

I tried something below without success. Is this even possible in R?

***see a desired file output below***

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

list_data<- list(one= data.frame(District=LETTERS[1:3], V1 = 1:3),
                 two= data.frame(District=LETTERS[3:8], V7 = 3:8, V3=8:3))

lapply(list_dat,\(j) 
    group_by(j,District) %>% 
      write.xlsx(file =paste0(j$District,".xlsx"), sheetName = ???)) # Not sure how to add subsheet names here
```

Here is one desired file for `District` C with 2 subsheets:
[image]

[image]

Comment: The answers to this question might be helpful: [Write data to different sheets of the same xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61822771/23067909)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrite the code as follows

```
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)

list_data<- list(one= data.frame(District=LETTERS[1:3], V1 = 1:3),
                 two= data.frame(District=LETTERS[3:8], V7 = 3:8, V3=8:3))

rv <- bind_rows(list_data) %>%
  distinct(District) %>%
  pull(District) %>%
  lapply(function(x) {
    sub_list <- lapply(names(list_data), function(y) {
      list_data[[y]] %>%
        mutate(subsheet = y) %>%
        relocate(subsheet) %>%
        filter(District == x)
    })
    names(sub_list) <- names(list_data)
    write.xlsx(sub_list, file =paste0(x,".xlsx"))
  })
```